# How can i launch a new pane in java FX immediately to the right of the previous pane within the same window/stage?

Tags: java, javafx

My goal is to have a program with 3 panes. A mulitfactor Auth. The first pane will have the user type in a passphrase, while the second pain will allow the user to pick a image from a drop down list. But I want the 3rd pane to launch just to the right of the 2nd pane after the use selects a image in the same "Main" stage.

Not looking for someone to code a program just point me in the right direction to what im trying to do. My searching skills are failing, either im not explaining it right or theres another word for this.

Edit:
[This is my idea of how i want it to work. Now that i look at it using a border pane probably makes since, But im still stuck with, How can I launch each section of the border at a different time, i.e when something is clicked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHgLj.png)

Answer (score 1):

I would go about it by having 3 panes side by side and just blank for the first FXML file you load in. I would then have another FXML file with the same layout that contains what you want to show up in those panes.

Then with that, you can have the controller on request (like when a user hits submit or however you are wanting these to show up) grab the content inside of the pane on the second FXML file by ID and load it into the pane.

I've done something similar with changing anchor panes and keeping the toolbar from the original so I can add more on this when I get home and should be able to supply some code that is modified to fit your issue.

*Edit 1*: Sorry I was in a hurry to submit that dive I had to go but I am on mobile now so I can edit but not able to add a lot, just felt I needed to say, there are different options for what you can use to do this which is why I just said a pane instead of anything specific. Just wanted to submit something so you can start looking in the right direction till I am able to update.

*Edit 2*: Alright now that I am home I tried this out and was able to get this working. Here is how I did it.

So I had two FXML files. One with the 3 areas that you have your items, however, only the box that you want to show when it starts is shown. Each area is enclosed by an AnchorPane. I used the AnchorPane as a container so I can swap out what is inside of it. I then had a second FXML file that had all of the boxes you want to show all of which enclosed in AnchorPanes. Here are pictures explaining what I mean.
[image: Image showing the two FXML files in Scene builder]
I have the first pane named `initial.fxml` and the second named `grabfrom.fxml`. For the pane names, I just have it as pane1, pane2, and pane3. Lastly, the methods I have are `show2()` and `show3()` and call them from the FXML when the respective buttons are clicked inside of the AnchorePanes.

With initial, I just load that up as normal from the start method in my main class and that is all that is needed to be done with that. We only had it so we could display something that does not have the boxes showing before needed.

**Now for the important part**

With what I have in `show2()`, which is called when the button inside of the first pane (which is there from the start) is pressed.

```
public void show2() throws IOException{
    AnchorPane toSetPane2=(AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("grabfrom.fxml"));
    toSetPane2=(AnchorPane) toSetPane2.lookup("#pane2");
    pane2.getChildren().setAll(toSetPane2);
}
```

What this is doing is loading the `grabfrom.fxml` into a temp var that we cast to an anchor pane. (Do note that this works since as you can see in the screenshot the whole FXML file is an anchor pane. If you're not using it that way you can take out the casting and cast to something you are using or not even cast depending on what it is.)

It then set the var we just made to just the AnchorPane we need, which is the second one since that's the one we are adding. It does this with the `.lookup("#ID");` method to get just the pane we need.

Lastly, it sets everything inside of the current `pane2` to `toSetPane2`.

This could all be compressed down into one line, however, I have left it as is for easier reading.

You should be able to use this method of loading in a portion of your application for loading in the third one and for that matter any other parts you want to in any situation.

*Edit 3*:

Also as @Swatarianess had said, there are stackpanes, this method will work with anything that you can set an ID to so they would work just as well. I used AnchorPanes because I have done a fair bit with them and had some code I could recycle whilst making a test for it so it was easier. All you would do if you were using those though is just cast to a StackPane instead of an AnchorPane like this:

```
public void show2() throws IOException{
    StackPane toSetPane2=(StackPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("grabfrom.fxml"));
    toSetPane2=(StackPane) toSetPane2.lookup("#pane2");
    pane2.getChildren().setAll(toSetPane2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The transition between panes could be done with a [stackpane](http://o7planning.org/en/10633/javafx-stackpane-layout-tutorial).

Comment: Checking that out now, The thought is to have all the panes open at once, and just to open the next pane to the right of the previous one all within the same AnchorPane.

Comment: With stackpane you can make it appear as the user is progressing through the authorisation process. It is worth a look.